# Trying to Upgrade Magento from ver. 2.3.4 to ver. 2.4.6 and causing Composer installation error

Tags: magento, composer-php

I was trying to upgrade Magento from ver. 2.3.4 to ver. 2.4.6
I have followed the steps mentioned here in tutorial, https://www.mgt-commerce.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-to-the-latest-version/ step by step as below

**1- Enabled the Maintenance Mode:** By using Terminal, i go in to the **bin** path and run the command

`php magento maintenance:enable`

which makes it enable and Terminal Shows the message: **Enabled maintenance mode**

**2- Run Upgrade Magento 2.4.6**: Then i run the below command to run the upgrade from Terminal,
`composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update`

But it Gives a **below Error:**

```
The "magento/magento-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") thatdoes not match your Composer installation ("2.6.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.

The "magento/inventory-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.6.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins"option.

The "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.6.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
```

along with following success message aswell
**./composer.json has been updated**

Looks i have some dependency issue,
Please can some one help me how can i get rid of and proceed

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your composer version is not correct.  You need to downgrade to 1.23 or below to get this to work.  You can always change back to the current composer version after the install.

Comment: this is strange, when i run the update, it start giving me following error.

[xv6khvzvx962@36]$ composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
./composer.json has been updated